# LINQ to SQL DataContext and IDisposable

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, linq-to-sql

I just in started working an a proj that uses LINQ to SQL.
I noticed the code is not using iDisposable, i myself would never pass a DataContext 
However since it is created in 1 method and passed to another do I need to do db.Dispose()
2 times, once per method or just once on the method that created the instance of DataContext?

```
  protected void btnSaveCC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var db = new DataContext();
            CCBadgeInfo(db);
        }


  private void saveCCInfo(DataContext db)
        {
            var currentCase = (Case)HttpContext.Current.Items["CurrentCase"];

            if (currentCase.TypeId == (int)prj.Constants.Constant..CreditFraud)
            {
                var applicant = db.Applicants.Where(a => a.ApplicantId == currentCase.ApplicantId).SingleOrDefault();
                applicant.CCExpirationDate = tryConvertDateTime(txtCCExpirationDate.Text);
            }

            db.SubmitChanges();
        }
```

Comment: Consensus is: no, there is no need to dispose: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/821574/c-sharp-linq-to-sql-should-datacontext-be-disposed-using-idisposable

Comment: And where is the code of your CCBadgeInfo ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only call it once. However, there shouldn't be any harm to call Dispose more than once: [Should IDisposable.Dispose() be made safe to call multiple times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306860/should-idisposable-dispose-be-made-safe-to-call-multiple-times)

In your case, you can either

```
protected void btnSaveCC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var db = new DataContext()) {
        CCBadgeInfo(db);
    }
}
```

Or just create and Dispose DataContext in saveCCInfo method.