# Amazon cannot access closed stream

Tags: c#, dispose

I am trying to use amazon `s3` libs but somehow can't pass stream to upload data to `s3`.

At the beginning I was using `using` statements but then rewrote it to `try catch dispose` and still I can't even dispose the stream, stream is not null but I get exception when trying to dispose that "cannot access closed stream" on the line `streamWriter?.Dispose()`;

```cs
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8);

try
{
    try
    {
        await streamWriter.WriteAsync(commandWithMetadata.SerializeToString());
        memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        var fileName = GetFileName(command);
        var request = new PutObjectRequest
        {
            BucketName = BucketName,
            Key = fileName,
            InputStream = memoryStream
        };

        await client.PutObjectAsync(request);
    }
    finally
    {
        streamWriter?.Dispose();
    }
}
finally
{
    memoryStream?.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Are you calling this async function like `= this_function().Result`? Also please go back to using `using` which is the correct way.

Comment: This code can leak because the resources are created *outside* the `try` block. Use `using` instead. There's no benefit from using `try/finally` like this.

Comment: Not part of the actual problem but the StreamWriter will dispose the given stream already (if you don't tell it to leave the stream open via the constructor). Currently you try to dispose the Memorystream twice. Actually a MemoryStream is ignorant to beeing disposed multiple times. In your real code is it a MemoryStream or something else?

Comment: @Ralf It is a principle in .NET that `Dispose` [may be safely called](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5306896/11683) on any object multiple times.

Comment: @GSerg good to know. Then i learned also now that a great deal of programmers i needed to use there code didn't adhere to that principle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following calling `await streamWriter.FlushAsync();` before `await client.PutObjectAsync(request);`.

But I think better approach would be:

```cs
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8, leaveOpen: true))
    {
        await streamWriter.WriteAsync(commandWithMetadata.SerializeToString());
    }
    memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    //... send
}
```

By default `StreamWriter` on dispose tries to flush remining data in buffer and close underlying stream (which seems to be already closed by `client.PutObjectAsync(request)`) so use `leaveOpen: true`. Also there is no need to use `try`-`finally`-`Dispose` (and not fully correctly) - there is [`using` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) which will do that for you.